# Aspxpopupcontorl using ContentURL property -> Is it possible to close the window via a server side button click event?

Tags: devexpress

Has anyone ever gotten this to work?

I have researched this several times over the last couple of years and have never found a solution to this issue.  I was asked to make this happen yet again today.

The contentURL property basically allows you to create another whole page to be used as the popupcontrol.

I have a button within this page that needs to perform server side logic (saving data) then I would like it to automatically close the window.

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/PopupControl/ContentUrl.aspx

Above is there demo link if you aren't aware of what this is.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated I seem to always have difficulty finding information on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [AspxCallback](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/Callback/Example.aspx) control.

You would need to turn off `AutoPostback`. When the user presses the button, use the `AspxCallback` to call the server side code then if the server side code successfully completes it should return a status back which you can check and then close the window if the save was successful. If the status you return indicates the save was unsuccessful then you  could display a message to your user and allow them to try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button_Click(object  sender,  EventArgs e)
{
  string script = string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> HidePopUp(); </script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "key", script);
}
```

c# above
jscript below

```
function HidePopUp() {
            var p = window.parent;
            var popup = p.window["testPopup"];
            popup.Hide();            
 }
```

Finally found something on their website.  Just make sure to replace testPopup with the clientside name of your popup control.